# How can I add copy to storybook stories in CSF (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storybook

I've implemented some stories in MDX with no format.  I'm using `@storybook/react` version `^6.3.12`.  Here's a brief example:

```
## Examples

### Dark Background

The same styling works on light or dark background.

*Due to a storybook bug, you cannot see dark-background stories in the Docs
page.  Use the Canvas page instead.*

<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Dark Background" 
    parameters={{
      backgrounds: {default: 'dark'}
    }}  
    args={{}}
  >
    {args => (
      <Selector assets={[...fixtures, ...fixtures]} />
    )}  
  </Story>
</Canvas>

### Few Assets

With only a few assets, the slider works the same way but without moving the 
thumbnails.

<Canvas>
  <Story name="Few assets" args={{}}>
    {args => (
      <Selector assets={[fixtures[0], fixtures[1]]} />
    )}  
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

Due to problems with MDX, I'm switching to CSF.  Here's a brief example (the second example from above).

```
export const FewAssets = (args) => (
  <Selector assets={[fixtures[0], fixtures[1]]} />
);
FewAssets.args = {...};
// and so on with parameters or whatever.
```

I've read the docs many times now.  I can't quite seem to figure out how to add copy to the page in CSF:

```
### Few Assets

With only a few assets, the slider works the same way but without moving the 
thumbnails.
```

I thought of just adding it into the story definition, but then the docs page shows all that markup when you look at the code sample.

Am I missing something obvious?